# Testing and debuggin application crashes C#

Tags: c#, crash

I have an application that after a few times if running it crashes. (application not responding).
when I try to attach my code to process I get assembly debugging, with no helpfull stack trace.

I'm unable to reproduce this from running in VS but only as an application. (therefor intellitrace - which I just read about but not very familiar is irrelevant)
Is there any tool I can use to assist understanding the root cause of the crash
Thanks!

Comment: Does it crash or stop responding? Those are two completely different things. And what is the stack trace of the main thread when it's in this situation? It might actually be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the event log or any other logs that your app might be writing to.

Find out if you can narrow down the minimal circumstances to repeat the crash/behavior so you can read the source code to trace the minimal scenario.

If the app does crash when running from VS check whether you are ignoring any exceptions. Look at the Debug | Exceptions dialog and have a look at the output view.

Check your code for Debug.Asserts that are removed from the Release build.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to use some kind of Logging system.
[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is very popular these days, you should have a look at it.

Furthermore, if you fix this bug but another one arises on your clients machines, you won't ask them to run a debugger for you, but they can provide you the log file ;-)